# Remove a value from hashmap, if key is empty remove the key as well

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public NobelPrizeWinners()
{
    winners = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();

    String[] people = new String[1];
    people[0] = "Barack H. Obama";
    winners.put(new Integer(2009), people);

    people = new String[1];
    people[0] = "Martti Ahtisaari";
    winners.put(new Integer(2008), people);

    people = new String[2];
    people[0] = "Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change (IPCC)";
    people[1] = "Albert Arnold (Al) Gore Jr.";
    winners.put(new Integer(2007), people);

    people = new String[2];
    people[0] = "Muhammad Yunus";
    people[1] = "Grameen Bank";
    winners.put(new Integer(2006), people);
   }
public void removeWinner(String nameOfWinnerToRemove)
{
    Set<Integer> allYears = winners.keySet();
    for(Integer year : allYears)
    {
        String[] eachYearWinners = winners.get(year);

        for (String winner : eachYearWinners) 
        {
            if(winner.equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfWinnerToRemove))
            {
                winners.remove(year, nameOfWinnerToRemove);

                if(eachYearWinners.length < 1)
                {
                    winners.remove(year);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove a winner(nameOfWinnerToRemove) given by the user, do nothing if no name matched. And, remove the key(Integer) if the key is empty.
Like, I want to remove "Barack H. Obama" in 2009, if I do this, there will be empty for 2009, then I must remove 2009. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Does it not work, or does it give you an exception because it is possible to get a ConcurrentModificationException running that code because you cannot iterate and remove from the actual set at the same time.

Comment: this is the second time this player homework assignment has had a question in a few minutes. Are you sure you should be cheating on homework?

Comment: Although it is a homework, my instructor allow to ask question when there is a problem. I don't know who is the player you mentioned, but that definitely not me. Make sure you are right when you are judging people.

Answer (score 1):

Important thing is if you want to remove any value from collection when iterating then use the `Iterator` provided by collection.

Please check if below code works for you .

```
public void removeWinner(String nameOfWinnerToRemove)
    {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator  = winners.keySet().iterator();

        //for(Integer year : allYears)
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Integer year = iterator.next();
            String[] eachYearWinners = winners.get(year);

            for (String winner : eachYearWinners)
            {
                if(winner.equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfWinnerToRemove))
                {

                    //winners.remove(year, nameOfWinnerToRemove); // ??? What is data type of winners I cant find remove method in a map that accepts two parameters
                    if(eachYearWinners.length < 1)
                    {
                        iterator.remove();// You should use Iterators Remove Method when you want to remove key in the iteration
                       // winners.remove(year);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yet this code is not work just like my code. What I want to do is remove a single value from a key that holds an array. My hashmap is hashmap<Integer, String[]>. I wonder if that is possible to remove only one value from a key. I tried winners.values().remove(nameOfWinnerToRemove), yet it doesn't remove anything at all.

Comment: Firstly I am curious  `winners.remove(year, nameOfWinnerToRemove);`  about this method. are you sure you didnt got any compile time error. also `winners.remove(year);` should have resulted in `concurretModificationException `

Comment: Do you want to remove winner value from `eachYearWinners  array` Then I think you should edit your question and say what is expected output when you have some sample Map provided.